# Proof for the distributivity of multiplication over addition for a Binary Field

Tags: finite-fields, alternative-proof

For the standard binary field $\mathbb{F}_{2} = \{0, 1\}$. Where the operations of addition and multiplication exist, and multiplication is equivalent to logical and, and addition is equivalent to logical exclusive or.

The field axiom of distributivity of multiplication over addition is:
$\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{F}_{2} \mspace{8mu} x(y + z) = xy +xz $

I understand I can make a truth table to demonstrate this, and I have been demonstrating that the binary field fulfills other field axioms, but I was wondering if there was another way. My mathematical toolkit isn't very large, so perhaps this is limiting me from seeing another standard way to demonstrate this.

Comment: In algebra courses this property is usually proven in a more general context of residue classes of integers modulo any (positive) integer $m$. Verifying this with the aid of a truth table is probably faster, but I still recommend that you look it up from that algebra book (something like a *first course in abstract algebra* is what you need).  Getting exposed to (preferrably familiar with) the idea of a congruence will usually pay dividends later.